# How make an admin action enabled or works just one time a year?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need to make an admin action enabled or works just one time a year is this possible
Here is the action :

```
def update_vacations(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for item in queryset:
        item.calculconge = item.calculVacation + item.VacationDays
        item.save()

update_vacations.short_description = "Update Vacations"
```

Comment: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-celery-beat-database-backed-periodic-tasks-with-admin-interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to save that information. there is no way around it. Either as a field on that model or a new one that only contains this information.

for example.

```
class VacationEdit(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(...)
    edited_year = models.IntegerField()
```

and in your signal do

```
for item in queryset:
    if VacationEdit.objects.filter(user=user, edited_year=current_year).exists():
        continue
    item.calculconge = item.calculVacation + item.VacationDays
    VacationEdit.objects.create(...)
    item.save()
```

But i would actually suggest to *not* edit old vacation data with new days but to make some kind of YearlyVacation-model and have one entry per year and just add new ones each year and save the old data.

Answer (score 0):

You could output the date to a file, and the when the person tries to perform the command, read the date from the file and compare it with the current date.

Comment: We have a big eco-system around saving data to a file and reading it again, thats what the *database* is, And its something Django is great with. Doing ad-hoc data saves to random files when you have a working database is not a very good idea if you dont have specific reasons.

Comment: Huh? Who is django?